# Swift Swipe Gesture Recognizer with overlapping UIViews

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, swipe, gesture

I have 2 UIViews, individually they work just fine. However once overlapped the lower UIView, UIView 2 does not register in the area that is covered by the upper UIView 1?

**UIView 1 (magenta) overlapping UIView 2 (lime)**

[image]

UIView 1 (magenta) accepts Left/Right swipe.

UIView 2 (lime) accepts Up/Down swipe.

**UIView 2 (lime) shown without the overlapping UIView 1 (magenta)**
[image]

```
@IBOutlet weak var swipeAB: UIView! 
@IBOutlet weak var swipeBC: UIView! 

func calculateAB(sender:UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {
    print("Swiped right, A to B")
}
func calculateBA(sender:UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {
    print("Swipe left, B to A")
}
func calculateBC(sender:UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {
    print("Swiped down, B to C")
}
func calculateCB(sender:UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {
    print("Swipe up, C to B")
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    moveAB.addTarget(self, action: #selector(GameViewController.calculateAB))
    moveAB.direction = .Right
    swipeAB.addGestureRecognizer(moveAB)
    moveBA.addTarget(self, action: #selector(GameViewController.calculateBA))
    moveBA.direction = .Left
    swipeAB.addGestureRecognizer(moveBA)
    moveBC.addTarget(self, action: #selector(GameViewController.calculateBC))
    moveBC.direction = .Down
    swipeBC.addGestureRecognizer(moveBC)
    moveCB.addTarget(self, action: #selector(GameViewController.calculateCB))
    moveCB.direction = .Up
    swipeBC.addGestureRecognizer(moveCB)
}
```

Comment: Could you separate the 2 UIViews into 3 UIViews? Then the top right UIView would have 2 gestures, and the rest would have 1? Not sure if you can do this according to what you are trying to do.

Comment: This did the trick, I uploaded a photo illustrating the answer.

Answer (score 1):

[impression7vx](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5009432/impression7vx), you were spot on, thanks!

I split the two overlapping UIViews up into:

- UIView 1 (magenta) to detect swipe right
- UIView 2 (yellow) to detect swipe left and swipe down
- UIView 3 (lime) to detect swipe up

[Split into 3 UIView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qa7Sx.png)

Comment: Awesome Awesome, glad I was able to help!